# BaseExpandableListAdapter find out which group an item was clicked in

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I have subclassed `BaseExpandableListAdapter` in the rows for the `BaseExpandableListView` I'm having a `CheckedTextView`. What I want to achieve is that there can only be checked items in one of the groups in the `BaseExpandableListView`.

So if there is already checked items in group 0 and the user tries to check any items in group 1 then a toast message should display saying something that he has to uncheck the items in group 0 or something like that.

So far my code looks like this:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        holder.checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
            }
        });


        holder.checkedTextView.setText(person.getName());
        holder.checkedTextView.setChecked(person.isTracked());

        return convertView;
    }
```

I suppose I need to get a reference or something to `BaseExpandableListView` inside the `onClick` method to find out which group the currently toggled `CheckedTextView` is inside?

I'm not sure if my terminology is correct since I just started coding on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it with the `int groupPosition, int childPosition` variables.